# How to implement tabulation in internet explorer browser using angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have fields in a form that i want to navigate from a field to an other using tab button on my keyboard.

i tried tabindex but it's working on chrome but not on internet explorer

```
    <form [formGroup]="parentForm">
      <div class="row">
      <label class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 control-label">du</label>
     <div class="col-sm-5">
    <p-calendar  [locale]="calendar" tabindex="1" class="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;"  #begin [placeholder]='x' dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" [formControlName]="componentName + 'beginDate'" [attr.disabled]="disableinput"
     ></p-calendar>
     </div>
<label class="col-sm-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 control-label">au</label>
<div class="col-sm-5">
  <p-calendar [locale]="calendar" tabindex="2" #end [placeholder]='x' 
 dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" [formControlName]="componentName + 'endDate'" 
   [attr.disabled]="disableinput"
   ></p-calendar>
     </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

i expect that tapping on tabs makes me navigate from calendar to an other but that does not work on internet explorer.

Comment: There is no `tabindex` attribute in the code you have provided. Please see [mcve] for information on posting code that allows us to reproduce your issue. As an aside, `tabindex` is supported by Internet Explorer so it is not a browser issue (see https://caniuse.com/#search=tabindex)

Comment: if i add tabindex like that it will be programmatically knowing where to go next after tabulation but i want it to do it without giving what the tabindex equals to ! beacause i dont know the next tab index is going to be ! i need to do it without saying tabindex="1" and got to tabindex="2" it should do it automatically